# Objective-c instance variable memory issues with ARC on

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, instance-variables

I have a largish objective-c iPhone project that runs fine, except that the memory use constantly increases while the app is in use, and never decreases. It does not increase while the app is not being actively used.

I have an almost identical Android app in Java that does not have this issue. After a lot of googling and experimenting I think the issue is that all of my class variables are instance variables, i.e they are declared in the .m files like below, and accessed using getters and setters.

```
@implementation SomeClass{
    NSString *someVariable;
    AnotherClass *anotherVariable;
}
```

There are a number of cases where two objects will have references to one another via the instance variables. I believe this is where the memory issues come from as I have read that the ARC will count each of these objects having 1 remaining pointer to them (from the other object) and therefore never release either from memory.

Ideally I'd like a solution that does not require moving all variables to the .h file, and also does not require changing the definition per variable, i.e I want a solution I can apply to all variables, although I don't know if this is possible. I think I am right in saying instance variables are 'strong', in that they increment the ARC reference count of that object, can I make all my instance variables 'weak', and if so would this be a good or bad idea?

Comment: FYI moving them to .h or .m doesnt matter. If you are moving them to .h you are making them public .

Comment: Ok, well I want them to be private, so is it possible to make them 'weak' also?

Comment: Objects referencing each other can cause problems. Have you considered having a parent and a child object? You could pass the properties that you need through to the child but the child only references the parent via weak properties.

Comment: @Dominic How do I make the child's reference to the parent weak?

Comment: We use weak reference for delegates, pointers, e.g. @ property (nonatomic, weak) id delegate.  For strings you can pass a copy of the object (to avoid the retain count problem) with @ property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *myString;

Comment: Thanks. Although as far as I can tell I can only do @ property for variables in the .h file, I am hoping to keep all my variables in them in .m file if possible. I may just move the parent reference variables to .h though if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved by putting __weak or __unsafe_unretained before instance variables that reference a parent class if that parent has a reference to the child. Using either means that the reference count for the parent object does not increase.

Use __unsafe_unretained if you want an exception to be thrown when you access the variable but the object has been release. Use __weak if you don't want an exception, the variable will become nil when the object is released.

```
@implementation SomeClass{
    NSString *someVariable;
    ChildClass *childVariable;
    __unsafe_unretained ParentClass *parentVar;
    __weak AnotherParentClass *AnotherParentVar;
}
```